# Can I use a WCF RESTful service from Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, rest, silverlight-3.0, service

I have a WCF RESTful service using the WebHttpBinding and I want to know if I can use this in Silverlight 3 without any modifications?

Comment: You should be able to, but without more information about WCF component we can't tell you definitively that you won't need to make changes.

Comment: well if you know how then tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make HTTP requests from a Silverlight client, so therefore yes you can access a WCF Restful service using WebHttpBinding.

What part of making an HTTP request do you not know how to do?

Comment: I was trying to use the client proxy created by adding  'service reference', but yes I agree I can in theory use a HTTP request for both same & cross domain services.

Comment: Just don't do it.  Using the client proxy will cause all sorts of bad habits.  MS have a great HTTP client library in their REST starter kit and someone has done a port of it to Silverlight here http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/02/wcf-rest-starter-kit-for-silverlight